# Variable contains None even after assignment

Tags: python, python-2.7, return

Here is a function that I wrote:

```
def conc(i,s,y):
    if sheet.cell(i+1,0).value != sheet.cell(2,0).value :
        # print s
        rtrns = s
        # print rtrns
        return rtrns

    else:
        if i==list1[len(list1)-1]:
            while i<(sheet.nrows):
                # print i
                s = s + " " + unicode(sheet.cell(i,y).value).encode('cp1252', 'replace')
                i+=1
            # print s
            rtrns = s
            # print rtrns
            return rtrns
        else:
            s = s + " " + unicode(sheet.cell(i+1,y).value).encode('cp1252', 'replace')
            #return s
            conc(i+1,s,y)
```

In the above function, when I print the value of rtrns in the first if block, it displays the value that I need.

But when I make a call to the function

```
c = conc(x,c,2)     #where x fetches an integer value as an index from a list
print c
```

it returns `None`

Comment: Where is your return statement in the else clause?

Comment: Whats wrong with the indentation? And else block doesnt need return statement, it makes a call to the function again recursively intil it satisfies one of the two blocks that have a return statement

Comment: 'def' and 'if' on the same indentation level???

Comment: Your function is not guaranteed to return. There are conditions where it won't return anything.

Comment: @user2799617: that was a mistake on my part that happened while copy pasting the code here.

Comment: @stacknewbie What happens, then, when that recursive block returns? What happens to the value when it reaches a point when it does return?

Comment: @juanchopanza: When i run the code using the debugger, in one step where the assignment is made to rtrns in the first if block, I can see the expected value assigned to it. But when the call is made, it stores None in it

Comment: @stacknewbie: You mixed tabs and spaces; in the editor tabs are shown as 8 spaces, the site renders them as 4 instead. Best to not use tabs *at all* for Python code indentation.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: thats where the problem is ..it prints the value but returns None

Answer (score 4):

The `return` statement is missing in the else part of your code

```
else:
    s = s + " " + unicode(sheet.cell(i+1,y).value).encode('cp1252', 'replace')
    #return s
    conc(i+1,s,y)
```

So, there is one code path, where nothing is returned from your recursive function `conc`.

Change the code and add a return

```
else:
    s = s + " " + unicode(sheet.cell(i+1,y).value).encode('cp1252', 'replace')
    #return s
    return conc(i+1,s,y)
```

A recursive call always **returns back to the caller**. So, when you recursively call `conc`, and one of the code path issues a return statement, the call gets back to **from where you invoked**. Another important thing is, a function **without an explicit return has an implicit return with None**.

The Following ASCII Art should be self explanatory of what might be going wrong

```
foo() <------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                                                                          |
    |                                                                          |
    |->def conc(...):                                                          |
           else:                                                             (None)
           .........                                                           |
              conc(i+1,s,y) <-------------------------------------------\      |
              return None  ----------------------------------------------U--- -|
               |                                                         |
               |                                                         | 
               \----->def conc(...):                                     |
                          else:                                        (None)
                          .........                                      |
                                conc(i+1,s,y) <----------------------\   |
                                return None   ------------------------U--|
                                |                                     |
                                |                                     |
                                |                                     |
                                \----------->def conc(...):        (rtrns)
                                                  if ... :            |
                                                  ..........          |
                                                      return rtrns----|
```

Comment: Probably you can explain also to where the first `return` statement return its value. =)

Comment: @justhalf: Does the ASCII Art explains well?

Comment: @Abhijit: Thanks a lot. It worked. Also, the explanation is very comprehensive. Cheers!

Comment: But why does it print the value but not return it?

Comment: return to whom? It prints the value `conc` has returned. None, is the value it returns and subsequently gets printed

Comment: I meant, in this         # print rtrns; return rtrns   in the first block, if i uncomment the print statement, the desired value gets printed.